# Use GeoCharts in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization, angular-directive

How can I use Google GeoChart in Angular? I want to inject angular data inside geoChart like this examples in Javascript https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?hl=it#Regions

```
function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Some advice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Angular Google Chart](https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart) can do this.

`bower install angular-google-chart --save`, then add `googlechart` to the app module dependencies.

```js
angular.module('app', ['googlechart'])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var chart1 = {};
  chart1.type = "GeoChart";
  chart1.data = [
    ['Locale', 'Count', 'Percent'],
    ['Germany', 22, 23],
    ['United States', 34, 11],
    ['Brazil', 42, 11],
    ['Canada', 57, 32],
    ['France', 6, 9],
    ['RU', 72, 3]
  ];

  chart1.options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    chartArea: {left:10,top:10,bottom:0,height:"100%"},
    colorAxis: {colors: ['#aec7e8', '#1f77b4']},
    displayMode: 'regions'
  };

  chart1.formatters = {
    number : [{
      columnNum: 1,
      pattern: "$ #,##0.00"
    }]
  };

  $scope.chart = chart1;
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.18/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.1.0/ng-google-chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div google-chart chart="chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/wiguxu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Any solution for Angular 6?